# React y Heroku deploy

Tags: reactjs, heroku

estoy desarrollando un pequeño proyecto con React. Quiero subirlo a Heroku y lo hago, desde Git, pero después de hacer el deploy, SIN mensajes de error, la página de la aplicación me sale vacía, tal que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en el repositorio vinculado el código está completo. ¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: Has probado abrir la consola de javascript para ver que error se muestra y ver por qué no carga la página?.

Comment: Hola, si, en ninguna consola me muestra ningun mensaje de error,

Comment: Hiciste el build de tu proyecto?